# How to update items in recycler view without updating the apk

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to update items in recycler view without updating the apk for instance  I have an app that would tell me every shoe released by Nike how can I add more items/shoes to my app or recycler view without updating the apk everytime I could just do it without notifying the user

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to connect your app to a backend web service that it would fetch data from. Then you would update the remote database on your server so the data content in your app would fetch the latest / newest data.

Comment: I don't know much about Firebase, but probably.